# Open Weather Map - add a form field function for city weather (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

The script I have works well, but I need an additional search field for city and I have some problems with this feature.

This is my code I have @ this time.

1. jQuery code

   ```
       $(function () { var DEG = 'c'; var weatherDiv = $('#weather'), scroller = $('#scroller'), location = $('div.location');
       if (navigator.geolocation) {
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationSuccess, locationError);
       } else {
           showError("Your browser does not support Geolocation!");
       }
   function locationSuccess(position) {
       try {
           var cache = localStorage.weatherCache && JSON.parse(localStorage.weatherCache);
           var d = new Date();
           if (cache && cache.timestamp && cache.timestamp > d.getTime() - 30 * 60 * 1000) {
               var offset = d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
               var city = cache.data.city.name;
               var country = cache.data.city.country;
               $.each(cache.data.list, function () {
                   var localTime = new Date(this.dt * 1000 - offset);
                   addWeather(
                       this.weather[0].icon,
                       moment(localTime).calendar() + ' Uhr',
                       this.weather[0].description,
                       '<span class="forecast-temp-blue">' + convertTemperature(this.main.temp_min) + '°' + DEG + '</span> | <span class="forecast-temp-red">' + convertTemperature(this.main.temp_max) + '°' + DEG + '</span>',
                       '<b>' + this.main.humidity + '%</b>',
                       '<b>' + miles2km(this.wind.speed) + '</b>',
                       '<b>' + convertDeg2Comp(this.wind.deg) + '</b>'
                   );
               });
               location.html(city + ', <b>' + country + '</b>');
               weatherDiv.addClass('loaded');
               showSlide(0);
           } else {
               var weatherAPI = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=' + position.coords.latitude + '&lon=' + position.coords.longitude + '&lang=de&callback=?';
               $.getJSON(weatherAPI, function (response) {
                   localStorage.weatherCache = JSON.stringify({
                       timestamp: (new Date()).getTime(),
                       data: response
                   });
                   locationSuccess(position);
               });
           }
       } catch (e) {
           showError("We can't find information about your city!");
           window.console && console.error(e);
       }
   }

   function addWeather(icon, day, description, temperature, humidity, windspeed, winddeg) {
       var markup = '<li>' +
           '<div class="row-body">' +
           '<div class="forecast-day">' + day + '</div>' +
           '<div class="forecast-cond">' + description + '</div>' +
           '<img src="assets/img/icons/' + icon + '.png" /><br>' +
           '<div class="forecast-left-side">' +
           '<div class="forecast-temp"><img src="assets/img/icons/temp.png" />' + temperature + '</div>' +
           '<div class="humidity"><img src="assets/img/icons/drop.png" />' + humidity + '</div>' +
           '</div>' +
           '<div class="forecast-right-side">' +
           '<div class="wind"><img src="assets/img/icons/wind.png" />' + windspeed + ' km/h</div>' +
           '<div class="windr"><img src="assets/img/icons/windr.png" />' + winddeg + '</strong></div>' +
           '</div></div></li>';
       scroller.append(markup);
   }
   var currentSlide = 0;
   weatherDiv.find('a.previous').click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       showSlide(currentSlide - 1);
   });
   weatherDiv.find('a.next').click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       showSlide(currentSlide + 1);
   });
   $(document).keydown(function (e) {
       switch (e.keyCode) {
       case 37:
           weatherDiv.find('a.previous').click();
           break;
       case 39:
           weatherDiv.find('a.next').click();
           break;
       }
   });
   function showSlide(i) {
       var items = scroller.find('li');
       if (i >= items.length || i < 0 || scroller.is(':animated')) {
           return false;
       }
       weatherDiv.removeClass('first last');
       if (i == 0) {
           weatherDiv.addClass('first');
       } else if (i == items.length - 1) {
           weatherDiv.addClass('last');
       }
       scroller.animate({
           left: (-i * 100) + '%'
       }, function () {
           currentSlide = i;
       });
   }
   function locationError(error) {
       switch (error.code) {
       case error.TIMEOUT:
           showError("A timeout occured! Please try again!");
           break;
       case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
           showError('We can\'t detect your location. Sorry!');
           break;
       case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
           showError('Please allow geolocation access for this to work.');
           break;
       case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
           showError('An unknown error occured!');
           break;
       }
   }

   function convertTemperature(kelvin) {
       return Math.round(DEG == 'c' ? (kelvin - 273.15) : (kelvin * 9 / 5 - 459.67));
   }
   function convertDeg2Comp(num) {
       val = Math.round((num - 22.5) / 45);
       arr = ["N", "NO", "O", "SO", "S", "SW", "W", "NW"];
       return arr[val % 8];
   }
   function miles2km(num) {
       val = (num / 0.62137).toFixed(2);
       return val;
   }
   function showError(msg) {
       weatherDiv.addClass('error').html(msg);
   }

   });
   ```

and here is my html code

```
        <div id="weather">
      <div class="location"></div>
      <ul id="scroller">
        <!-- The forecast items will go here -->
      </ul>
      <a href="#" class="arrow previous">Previous</a> <a href="#" class="arrow next">Next</a>
      <form id="search">
        <input id="getcity" name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Stadtname" onclick="httpGetCity()"/>
      </form>
      <input id="gloc" type="submit" title="W3C Geolocation" value="" />
    </div>
```

The user should have the possibility to enter a city name and the weather data should be displayed in the same widget for the entered city.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: you need to use an additional web service to turn the city name into a lat/lon pair...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but tell me why i must turn the city into lat/long pair.

Comment: Openweathermap api has also some features to get weather with city name ->  http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London&lang=de&callback=test I tried to integrate this, but unfortunately it did not work.